# Trying to generate all sentences of a simple formal grammar

Tags: python, queue, grammar, formal-languages

I am new to python and trying to generate all sentences possible in the grammar.
Here is the grammar:

```
  #set of non terminals
  N = ('<subject>', '<predicate>', '<noun phrase>', '<noun>', '<article>', '<verb>',   '<direct object>')
  #set of teminals

  T = ('the', 'boy', 'dog', 'bit')
  #productions
  P = [ ('Sigma',           ['<subject>', '<predicate>']), \
  ('<subject>',       ['<noun phrase>']),            \
  ('<predicate>',     ['<verb>']),                   \
  ('<predicate>',     ['<verb>','<direct object>']), \
  ('<noun phrase>',   ['<article>','<noun>']),       \
  ('<direct object>', ['<noun phrase>']),            \
  ('<noun>',          ['boy']),                      \
  ('<noun>',          ['dog']),                      \
  ('<article>',       ['the']),                      \
  ('<verb>',          ['bit'])                       ]
```

Here is my attempt, I am using a queue class to implement it methodically,

```
# language defined by the previous grammar.
Q = Queue()
Q.enqueue(['Sigma'])
found = 0
while 0 < len(Q):
    print "One while loop done"
    # Get the next sentential form
    sf = Q.dequeue()
    sf1 = [y for y in sf]
    for production in P:
        for i in range(len(sf1)):
                if production[0] == sf1[i]:
                        sf[i:i+1] = [x for x in production[1]]
                        Q.enqueue(sf)
                        Q.printQ()
```

I am getting in infinite loop, and also I am facing some issue with shallow-deep copy, if I change one copy of sf, everything in queue changes too. Any help is appreciated, any directions, tips would be great

Here is the expected output:

```
       The dog bit the boy
       The boy bit the dog
       The boy bit the boy
       The dog bit the dog
       The dog bit
       The boy bit
```

Comment: Your indentation is broken. Recopy it from your source file, then select the code and press Ctrl-K to format it. If you don't get the indentation right, we can't tell how Python thinks your code is structured.

Comment: I have fixed the indentation. This is all I did, as I am getting in an infinite loop. Thanks for taking a look. Appreciate it

Comment: You're asking us to write your algorithm for you.

Comment: No sir, I want to know how to approach it, I want to know what am I doing wrong. I havent done much and I am getting stuck, so I wish to understand How to approach it.

Comment: I have tried it many times, but I am getting stuck with wrong answer or infinite loop. I would appreciate if you could share how could it be approached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am facing some issue with shallow-deep copy, if I change one copy of sf, everything in queue changes too

Yes. In Python, a list is an object with its own identity. So:

```
Q.enqueue(['Sigma'])
```

creates a (one-element) list and enqueues a reference to it.

```
sf = Q.dequeue()
```

pops that reference from Q and assigns it to variable 'sf'.

```
sf[i:i+1] = ...
```

makes a change to that list (the one that 'sf' refers to).

```
Q.enqueue(sf)
```

enqueues a reference to that same list.

So there's only one list object involved, and Q just contains multiple references to it.

Instead, you presumably want each entry in Q to be a reference to a separate list (sentential form), so you have to create a new list for each call to Q.enqueue.

Depending on how you fix that, there might or might not be other problems in the code. Consider:

(1) Each sentence has multiple derivations, and you only need to 'find' one (e.g., the leftmost derivation).

(2) In general, though not in your example grammar, a production's RHS might have more than one occurrence of a non-terminal (e.g. if COND then STMT else STMT), and those occurrences need not derive the same sub-forms.

(3) In general, a grammar can generate an infinite set of sentences.

---

By the way, to copy a list in Python, instead of saying

```
copy = [x for x in original]
```

it's simpler to say:

```
copy = original[:]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, It worked. Once I resolved the copy issue, by print statements I could see what was wrong with my implementation. I was scanning all non terminals together. By just scanning one non terminal, and then finding its match in all productions did the trick, and yes, this was just a sample grammar to understand how things work, it was just framed by us to understand if we could code it in python. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple grammar that allows to specify different sentences in terms of alternatives and options. Sentences that are described with that grammar can be parsed. The attributed grammar is described using Coco/R for which there is a python version (http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Coco/#Others). I am more familiar with C# so I created a C# project here that can work as an example for you: https://github.com/abeham/Sentence-Generator.

For instance, parsing "(This | That) is a [nice] sentence" with the parser of that simple grammar creates four sentences:
* This is a sentence
* This is a nice sentence
* That is a sentence
* That is a nice sentence

Only finite sentences can be created with that grammar since there is no symbol for repetition.

I know that there already exists an accepted answer, but I hope that this answer will also be of value to those, like me, that arrived here looking for a generic solution. At least I didn't find anything like that on the web, which is why I created the github project.

Comment: This worked really well. You haven't mentioned this explicitly but your code also supports nested structures like This is a [(nice|great)] sentence. Thank you!